# Bound on number of terms in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given some number n, and 
Given the sequence $\left\{2,3,\ldots,\frac n2\right\}$ in which we represent terms as $a_i$, $1 \le i \le \frac n2-1$

I need to show a bound on the size of any subset p of the sequence that can make the following equation true:

$$\sum_{a_k \in p} \frac{1}{a_k} \leq 8$$

I am trying to bound $|p|$ (I am hoping to show that it is no bigger than $O(\log n)$

Comment: Yes, thank you. That tells me that there are about n terms in the sum (and the goal of showing log n terms makes no sense:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all sure I understand the question, but suppose $${1\over r}+{1\over r+1}+\cdots+{1\over n}$$ is about 8, then $\log n-\log r$ is about 8, so $n/r$ is about $e^8$, so the number of terms in the sum is about $(1-e^{-8})n$.